# How to redirect to self keeping viewstate?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, viewstate

I would like to redirect to the same page after form is submitted. But there are other controls on the page, witch state I want to keep.

Ho can I solve this? Is good way to try to store viewstate into session and then load it back after forwarding? Or is here other better solution?

Comment: What other controls do you want to keep? You are leaving the page and navigating away from it.

Comment: GridView pager (select box), its ordering, DetailView displays selected record, subforms with its controls etc... Second part of your question I do not understand. At the end, I leave every page. :-)